# Changing the amount Ether sent out by a function?

Tags: solidity, contract-development

So I recently started smart contract development (not my first time coding I have some experience in Java) and I created a basic contract called Allowance.sol. The problem occurs when I try to change the set ETH value in the smart contract after it's been deployed, I have been able to change the address it gives the ETH too and the owner but not the value or the time, is there any way I can do this?

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.21;

import "./Ownable.sol";

    contract Allowance is Ownable{
        uint AllowanceWeek = 0.01 ether;
        address ledger;
        uint32 coolDownTime = 1 weeks;
        uint32 overflow;
        uint32 weekCooldown;

        modifier onlyLedgerOrOwner{
            require(msg.sender == ledger || msg.sender == owner);
            _;
        }

        function _triggerCooldown()internal onlyOwner{
          weekCooldown = uint32(now + coolDownTime);
      }

        function () public payable{

        }

        function _changeCoolDownTime(uint32 _CoolDownTime) external onlyOwner{
            coolDownTime = _CoolDownTime;
        }

        function withdraw() external payable onlyLedgerOrOwner {
            require(now >= weekCooldown);
            require(this.balance >= AllowanceWeek);
            ledger.transfer(AllowanceWeek);
            _triggerCooldown();
            overflow = uint32(this.balance - (AllowanceWeek * 76));
            if(overflow > 0){
                msg.sender.transfer(overflow);
            }
      }

      function _setAllowance(uint _Allowance) external onlyOwner{
          AllowanceWeek = _Allowance;
      }

      function _changeAddress(address _Address) external onlyOwner{
          ledger = _Address;
      }

      function transferOwnership (address newOwner) onlyOwner{
        require(newOwner != address(0));
        OwnershipTransferred(owner, newOwner);
        owner = newOwner;  
    }  
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean you "can't change" the values?

Answer (score 2):

I don't get what you are exactly asking but I will suppose you are having issues with changing the values of `AllowanceWeek` and `coolDownTime`.

---

You have to think in Ethereum/Solidity.

You see that the `AllowanceWeek` variable, which holds the amount in ether is a `uint256` type. But `ether` isn't a type, so what is it? It seems to be an alias, but an alias for what? What is the smallest unit, ether-wise? It's the `Wei`, right? So, the value held by your `AllowanceWeek` variable isn't `0.01` but `10000000000000000`. As a reminder, `1 ether == 10**18 Wei`, you can use [an online converter](https://etherconverter.online/) if you are lazy.

As for `coolDownTime`, it's the same. `weeks` is an alias for it's equivalent in seconds, which is the unit used too. So, when you want to change `coolDownTime`, it's `60*60*24*7 = 604800` * `number of weeks`.